# Mean Value Theorem x(0 , +infinity) (1+x)^a>1+ax.

Tags: calculus

I must show that
$$(1+x)^a>1+ax ..ifa>1$$
$$(1+x)^a<1+ax ..if..0<a<1$$
$$x(0,+∞)$$
using mean value theorem.What i have done so far.
$$(1+x)^a-1-ax>0 ..if..a>1$$
$$(1+x)^a-1-ax<0 ..if..0<a<1$$
using mvt $$f'(x)={f(b)-f(a) \over b-a}$$
$$f(x)=(1+x)^a-1-ax$$
$$f'(x)=a(1+x)^a-1-1$$
$$f(a)=f(0)=1^a-1$$
I cannot understand b value is gone be f(b)=?

Comment: for small h ....use a=m;b=m+h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) = x^a.$

1) Let $a>1:$

$\dfrac{f(1+x) -f(1)}{x}= f'(c)$, $1 <c <1+x$.

$(1+x)^a = 1 + x (ac^{a-1} ) > 1+ ax$ ,

since $c^{a-1} >  1^{a-1} =1;$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: What am i missing peter?
Why 1<c<1+x?

Comment: Nick. MVT: (f(a)-f(b))/(a-b) = f'(c) , where c \in (a,b), ( a >b.) c , in any textbook.Makes sense?

Comment: ok i got it.thanks for your help.

Comment: Nick.Try 0<a<1. If you run into a problem, we try again.